# Submit form, process info with script, and display results on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am basically trying to do the same as this person:

[jQuery - submit form via AJAX and put results page into a div...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712833/jquery-submit-form-via-ajax-and-put-results-page-into-a-div)

This is, submit a form and display a message on the same page after a successful submission.

However, my case is slightly different.  I am using a script that allows me to e-mail links to download files, and this script controlls the success or failure messages. In adittion, I am using a CMS, Joomla.

So, the way this normally works is like this:

You fill out a form on a page and press send.  After submission, you see an html page with a thank you message.  If anything goes wrong, you see a failure message. If everything goes well you receive an email with a link to download the files.

To be able to do this one must do the following:

**1) Add the following line on top of the page (call the script):**

```
<?php require_once("myscript.php"); ?>
```

**2) Add the form**

The form's action must be the script file:

```
<form action="myscript.php" method="post">
```

**3) Tell the script the parameters for the e-mail:** which files, expire time for links, and very importantly the address of the return url, which can be the one with the thank you message.  The other parameters are not important really.

```
<?php emailfunction('myfile.zip',15,1,'thankyou.html',0); ?>
```

What I want to do is to be able to show a message on the same page after submission, as the example mentioned at the beginning of this post. Ideally, hide the form and show the message. However, I haven't managed to do it.

I think my problem is that I don't know how to:

> tell the server to send back only the portion of the HTML that you
>   want to use to populate the DIV (which is the more efficient way), or
>   pick out the specific html from the server response that you want,
>   e.g. $("#someDiv").html($(html).find('#results'));

As the author of the answer in the previous example indicates.

When something goes wrong, I get sent to the address specified inside the script like this:

```
$ErrorTemplate="/home/server/public_html/errortemplate.html";
```

If I delete the thankyou.html address from here:

```
<?php emailfunction('myfile.zip',15,1,'thankyou.html',0); ?>
```

I get sent to the address specified in the action parameter of the form.

So what I think I am missing, but I have no idea how to fix, is an answer from the script that can then be processed by the jQuery.  I also tried this:

http://support.webvanta.com/support_article/615726-submitting-forms-with-ajax

But it didn't work either.

I have been in touch with the developer of the script but, even though he's a really nice guy, he says he doesn't know anything about jQuery nor Ajax, so he cannot really help me.

You can see the form I am using here:

http://perrerac.org/musica/chile/congreso/397-congreso-congreso

If you check the header you'll find a file: perrerac.org/downloader/ajaxsubmitform.js

Which is an attempt to replicate the example in the post aforementioned.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: can pull apart page sent back, assuming is correct and joomla doesn't do a redirect as result of ajax for some reason. When you currently submit with ajax....does email processor do as expected? You can inspet an actual request within a browser console to see exactly what does get sent back also. If it is what you want...the rest is fairly easy

Comment: Nothing actually happens, but I do get the files sent to my e-mail.  Now, I don't know if it's using ajax or not really, I completely newby to this, sorry :( You can see it by yourself here:  
http://perrerac.org/musica/chile/congreso/397-congreso-congreso

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of submitting with ajax and getting part of returned full page and using just that snippet of html to insert in current page

This assumes that joomla doesn't do some redirect to unwanted page as a result of processing via ajax.

```
/* using very generic selector for form, should use more unique one to that form*/

$('form').submit(function(event){
     /* prevent normal browser submit*/
      event.preventDefault();
     /* do some validation, return if invalid*/

      /* collect the data to send*/
     var data=$(this).serialize();
     /* using shortcut method $.post, can use $.ajax for access to all options and more flexibility if needed*/
     $.post('path/to/action', data,function( responseHtml){
         /* create a jQuery object out of returned page for finding html needed*/
         var $newPage= $(responseHtml);
          /* find id=results div in new page, insert in id=someDiv*/
         $("#someDiv").html( $newPage.find('#results'));
         /* if need to run any code on results html, do it here, it exists now in page*/

     }).error(function(){
           alert('Ooooops');
     });  
});
```

Comment: Hi again, I have tried your method, but it doesn't work.  I think it's because of the way the script works actually.  I imagine the only way to be able to implement what I want is to -in some way- modify the method used by the script to send a response back.  I don't know, I'm too newbie at PHP and Javascript to really know.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: make sure code wrapped in `$(document).ready`...use a browser console/developer tools to inspect requests to ee if they are made, their status , what is sent and returned (if anything). Best place to start to debug. Also use console to check errors thrown