# Post form with ajax and update div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I want to post simple form with ajax and update content of div (id result), but I get redirected to server.php file.

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form id="wbForm" action="server.php" method="POST">
    Date1: <input type="text" name="date1" value="2000-01-21"><br>
    Date2: <input type="text" name="date2" value="2000-01-02"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    <div id="result"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax.js:

```
$(document).ready(function showHint(form) {

    $.ajax({
    type:'POST', 
    url: 'server.php', 
    data:$('#wbForm').serialize(), 
    success: function(response) {
        $('#wbForm').find('.result').html(response);
    }});
});
```

server.php:

```
<?php

$input=$_POST; 
//... compute something

echo "result";
?>
```

String "result" should appear in div with id=result, but I get redirected to /server.php where I can see "result", why?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're not actually calling `showHint()`. And even if you were, you're not preventing the default submit behavior of the form.

Comment: You need to bind the ajax function to your submit button. Read up one of the many, many php/jquery/ajax tutorials on form submitting and response.

Comment: Dupe? "jQuery - submit form via AJAX and put results page into a div…?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712833/jquery-submit-form-via-ajax-and-put-results-page-into-a-div

Comment: Your `find('result')` is kinda pointless. result's an ID, so `$('#result').html(response)` would be more efficient.

Comment: And also remove `action="server.php"` since you're handling it elsewhere.

Comment: `find('.result')` isn't just "kinda" pointless, it's completely pointless since there aren't any elements with class `result` in that form.

Comment: So I have checked console, I had path to jquery.js wrong as well as other things as you pointed out. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form id="wbForm" action="server.php" method="POST">
    Date1: <input type="text" name="date1" value="2000-01-21"><br>
    Date2: <input type="text" name="date2" value="2000-01-02"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    <div id="result"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax.php

```
$(document).on("ready", function(){
//Form action
$("#wbForm").on("submit", function(event){
    // Stop submit event
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST', 
        url: 'server.php', 
        data:$('#wbForm').serialize(), 
        success: function(response) {
            $('#wbForm').find('.result').html(response);
        }});
    });
});
```

server.php

```
<?php
$input = $_POST;
print_r( $input );
?>
```

Happy Codding!!

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues. First, you are getting redirected to server.php when you hit submit because of your form action "server.php". If you want the AJAX call to happen when clicking the button you should put the AJAX call in a JavaScript function and call that function onclick()

The reason the jQuery .AJAX call isn't triggering success is because it's expecting JSON. Try:

```
<?php
header("content-type:application/json");
$input=$_POST; 
//... compute something

echo json_encode("result");
?>
```

Hope this helps.